# Wordpress Arabic Permalinks not working

Tags: wordpress, arabic, permalinks

My website is in Arabic and also my posts URLs, whenever I click on the post it would redirect me to the "archive"  of the month and won't send me to the post itself. 
the link looks like this for example: [http://www.mywebsite.com/2015/7/3/تجربة](http://www.mywebsite.com/2015/7/3/%D8%AA%D8%AC%D8%B1%D8%A8%D8%A9) but yet it won't redirect me properly

Answer (score 0):

Try This Function and Check It

```
get_permalink();
```